# Perché in Italiano la doppia q si scrive cq?

Tags: orthography, geminate-consonants

Come dice il titolo, in Italiano la forma geminata di *qu* (foneticamente /kʷ/) è scritta *cqu* invece che il più naturale *qqu*, con l'eccezione della parola *soqquadro* (e, possibilmente, *beqquadro*, anche se io ho in pratica sempre incontrato la forma *bequadro* con la consonante semplice).

A che punto della storia dell'italiano è stata presa questa insolita decisione? Sono note le ragioni?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Il testo di Massimo Fanfani pubblicato sulla *Crusca per voi* n. 20 (aprile 2000), in risposta alla domanda "Soqquadro: ma perché?", è molto esaustivo:

> La lettera *q*, ereditata dall’alfabeto latino, compare solo nella sequenza *qu* per rappresentare il cosiddetto nesso labiovelare (costituito da una occlusiva velare sorda, la *q*, e dalla *u* semiconsonante), ed è una lettera in sovrappiù perché indica il medesimo suono indicato dalla *c*, come si nota confrontando *cuoco* e *quoto*, *scuola* e *squalo*; le grafie diverse si giustificano solo risalendo al latino *cocus* e *quotus*, *scola* e *squalus*.
>   Per questa ragione la *q* “ottiene anche le stesse proprietà” della *c*, come si legge nel *Vocabolario* della Crusca (1612), “salvo che, dovendosi raddoppiare, il *c* gli si pone davanti, in sua vece, come *acqua*, *acquisto*”.
>
> Le uniche deroghe a quest’uso generale del raddoppiamento del *q* compaiono, appunto, in *soqquadro* (*soqquadrare*, *soqquadrato*) e in un altro caso, *biqquadro* (e, sul suo esempio talora anche in *beqquadro*). Come spiegare questa insolita e circoscritta grafia *qq*? Essa è nata certamente per analogia: dato che i rafforzamenti nella maggior parte dei casi vengono indicati raddoppiando il segno della consonante, sul modello di *sommossa* e *soppiatto*, si è fatto anche *soqquadro*. Va detto inoltre che fino a tutto il Quattrocento la forma di raddoppiamento della *q* fu oscillante e perfino il nostro *soqquadro* fu scritto *socquadro*. E ancora Claudio Tolomei nel Polito (1525) scrive *aqqua* accanto ad *acquistarsi* e *piacque*. I grammatici cinquecenteschi, a partire dal Fortunio, optarono invece per la grafia latineggiante *cq* e così essa si impose rapidamente e universalmente. I nostri due termini, entrambi abbastanza defilati, l’uno appartenendo al linguaggio tecnico dei musicisti, l’altro, come risulterebbe da un’annotazione al Malmantile del Lippi, al gergo di muratori e artigiani, riuscirono a fissarsi nell’uso scritto con il loro raddoppiamento analogico e in questa forma sono giunti fino ad oggi.
>
> In passato c’è stato chi era favorevole all’eliminazione di tali residui grafici, come Amerindo Camilli (Pronuncia e grafi a dell’italiano, 1956, p. 38): “*Biqquadro* e *soqquadro* sono due eccezioni fastidiose e assurde: quindi noi siamo d’opinione che si possa e sia meglio scrivere *bicquadro* e *socquadro*”. Ma considerando che eccezioni e incongruenze nella grafia si sono sempre tollerate in ogni lingua, e che in fin dei conti nel nostro caso si tratta di due termini innocui e piuttosto rari, credo convenga continuare a scriverli così come sono stati tramandati, e a riguardarli anzi con un certo rispetto, dal momento che, riuscendo a scampare fortunosamente all’opera normalizzatrice dei grammatici, ci mostrano ancora gli unici campioni superstiti di un vecchio modo di raddoppiare la *q*.

Comment: Gran parte delle “parole capricciose”, come vengono (o venivano) chiamate alle elementari, *cuore* *cuoio* *scuola* non sono affatto capricciose, perché presentano il dittongo mobile. Molto più capricciose sono *questo* *quello* *qui* *qua*, in cui la *q* non è etimologica.

Comment: @egreg: Vero! È solo un'ipotesi, ma essendo tutti composti per fusione di voci pronominali latine - _(ec)cu(m) istum_, _(ec)cu(m) illum_, _(ec)cu(m) hic_, _(ec)cu(m) hac_ - magari anche qui c'è lo zampino dei grammatici cinquecenteschi. In tal caso potrebbe aver giocato un ruolo il fatto che il nominativo _qui_ si è trasformato nell' italiano _chi_, mentre il dativo _cui_ è rimasto invariato, sicché _(ec)cu(m) hic_ > _qui_ potrebbe aver fatto strada alle altre grafie. Oppure più probabilmente sto delirando. :D

Comment: @VincenzoOliva Penso che la differenza più evidente tra *cui* e *qui* sia fonetica: *qui* è pronunciato /kʷi/, mentre *cui* è pronunciato /kui/. Ha senso riservare il digrafo *qu* per la pronuncia di /kʷ/. Sono meno certo riguardo alla grafia di *cuore*, *cuoio* e *scuola*. Quasi quasi potrei porre un'altra domanda nei prossimi giorni

Comment: @DenisNardin: Hai ragione, la presenza o meno del dittongo distingue le due parole. Direi quindi che indipendentemente da _qui_ > _chi_, è presumibile che quei composti con _eccum_ avrebbero comunque preso la _q_.

Comment: La “c” in *scuola* è etimologica “schola>scuola”; in *cuore* è dovuta al dittongo mobile: *cuore*, *coricino* (anche se è più frequente, al giorno d'oggi, *cuoricino*), come in *cuoio* e *coriaceo*.